# Unregistered user login for wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

Is there a way where we can login as a subscriber/customer in a wordpress website? I have developed a website for a client of mine. It's a club & hotel management website & they have 6000 members registered. We have login of all 6000 members in an SQL database & I want to use that SQL database for user login(besides usage of mysql).

Let me know if there's a possibility to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest read this topic http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service/11472#11472 it covers your question really carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to provide a customized login experience for your subscribers. It may be a long process, but **it would work easily:**

1. First thing you need to do is install and activate the [WPForms](https://wpforms.com/) plugin.
2. Upon activation, you need to visit WPForms » Settings page to enter your license key. You can get this license key from your account on WPForms website.
3. After verification, you need to head over to WPForms » Addons page.
4. Click on the Install Addon button.
5. Visit WPForms » Add New page. This will launch WPForms’ form builder.
6. You need to enter a form name and then from ‘Select a Template’ section click on ‘User Registration Form’ template.
7. Add new fields you want to add from the left panel as well as customize the order of existing fields by using a simple drag and drop interface.
8. Once you are done adding the fields, click on the ‘Settings’ menu on the left and then select the ‘User Registration’ tab.
9. Click on the save button at the top right corner of the screen to save your form settings.
10. Simply create a new WordPress page or edit an existing page that you would like to use as registration page.
11. On the page edit screen, you will notice the ‘Add Form’ button. Clicking on it will bring up a popup where you can select the user registration form you just created.
12. Click on the ‘Add Form button’ and you will notice a WPForms shortcode will appear in the post editor.
    You can now save or publish your page. Visit the page in a new browser tab to see your custom user registration page in action.
13. Visit WPForms » Add New page. This will launch the Form Builder interface of WPForms. You need to provide a name for your custom login form and then select ‘User Login Form’ as your template.
14. Next you need to click on the settings tab and then click on ‘Confirmation’ tab. This is where you can define what to do after a successful login.
    You can show users a message, redirect them to the page they came from, or redirect them to any other page on your site.
15. Click on the Save button and now You can add your custom login form to a page by creating a new page and then clicking on the Add Form button.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I was looking for. I have disabled the registration in the website but I have another database where the user login is stored. We have around 6000 users with their login credentials in a SQL database & I wanted to link it with the wordpress (parallelly running with MySQL database but only used for users login).